# how to get huge AD group membership list in CSV

Tags: powershell

How would i extract all membership (user name + logon name) part of AD group in csv format ? the group contain more than 15K users.

I'm getting this error:
get-adgroupmember : The size limit for this request was exceeded

Comment: Hi User123, welcome to SO! SO is not a code writing site and this question isn't applicable here. Try editing your question to add more detail and more suitable for this site or try posting this on a different site! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want us to help, try posting your attempts and provide more detail and information on **what exactly you are trying to do. We cannot help you if you don't help us understand :)**